# sub or function not defined error in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a code that I found also here. the code is removing duplicates on each column on each spreed sheet on a workbook treating it as a separate entity. whenever I try to run the code the compiler error says "sub or function not defined" and there is a yellow highlight on the most upper part and the "LastCell" got a blue highlight. I already add the solver reference but still it gives me the same error. I just can't figure out what the problem is if it's on the code or should I add another reference.

```
Sub Removeduplicates()

    Dim ws As Workbook
    Dim lLastcol As Long
    Dim lLastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long


    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lLastcol = LastCell(ws).Column

        For i = 1 To lLastcol

            lLastrow = LastCell(ws, i).Row

            With ws
                .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lLastrow, i)).Removeduplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
            End With


        Next i

   Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post code in the question as text and not as an image.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like lasy cell is the function you thought you had.  We is the worksheet passed in.  Thee function will use something like

```
Function lastcell(w as worksheet) as range
   Set Lastcell=w.range("a" & w.rows.count).end(xlup)

End function
```

Comment: Since when is a [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)?

Comment: Sorry, I was typing on my tablet on the way into work.

Comment: You still need to `Set` a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and if you look at the two occurances of the `LastCell` function in the code, one of them uses an optional column parameter and neither of them asks for the last cell in column A unless column A was the only populated column on the worksheet. This response would appear to be in the middle of [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUaw.png) group.

Answer (score 1):

After deciphering your code snippet, this is the best that I can come up with.

```
Function lastCell(ws As Worksheet, _
                  Optional c As Variant, _
                  Optional r As Variant) As Range
    With ws
        If IsMissing(c) And IsMissing(r) Then
            Set lastCell = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
        ElseIf IsMissing(c) And Not IsMissing(r) Then
            Set lastCell = .Cells(r, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        ElseIf IsMissing(r) And Not IsMissing(c) Then
            Set lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp)
        Else
            Set lastCell = .Cells(r, c)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Copy that code to a module code sheet in your VBA project. It can tested with a short sub procedure like the following.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet

    Debug.Print lastCell(ws1).Address(0, 0)      '<~~ last cell on worksheet
    Debug.Print lastCell(ws1, 3).Address(0, 0)   '<~~ last used cell in column C
    Debug.Print lastCell(ws1, , 4).Address(0, 0) '<~~ last used column on row 4
End Sub
```

Comment: you mean I will copy the code to another module?  thanks for helping me by the way.

Comment: No, you can just paste it underneath the Removeduplicates sub you already have. It just cannot go into a worksheet code sheet (e.g. Sheet1); it has to be a module code sheet (e.g. Module1).

Comment: hope you don't mind if I ask why there is type mismatch run time error when i try to run the code and it highlights the For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Comment: Should have been `Dim ws As Worksheet` not `Dim ws As Workbook` in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the solution of Darren Bartrup-Cook [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654461/excel-to-remove-duplicates-one-column-at-a-time-for-many-columns), make sure to copy the function `LastCell` to your code as well.