# Multiple column searching for email address, find duplicate value and delete

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, formula

I am in emergency situation. Any help from expert would be much appreciated.Apologies as it has been asked several time. I have tried in lots of way.But nothing seems can solve my problem.

My query is I have 3 column and all have email address. I want to run something where it will identify any duplicate among all column and delete the duplicate keeping original value. I have tried remove duplicate but it only work for one column. i have used excel 2013.I have shared my data and recent VBA code that  have took from here with  you.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iCvKBZbuOyWAzDvKfRvDgT41x8VQO-V-OXMgcBbJQko/edit?usp=sharing

Sub RemoveDups()

```
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim lLastCol As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Work through each sheet in the workbook.
For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Find the last column on the sheet.
    lLastCol = LastCell(wrkSht).Column

    'Work through each column on the sheet.
    For i = 1 To lLastCol

        'Find the last row for each column.
        lLastRow = LastCell(wrkSht, i).Row

        'Remove the duplicates.
        With wrkSht
            .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lLastRow, i)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    Next i

Next wrkSht
```

End Sub

'This function will return a reference to the last cell in either the sheet, or specified column on the sheet.
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Col As Long = 0) As Range

```
Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

On Error Resume Next

With wrkSht
    If Col = 0 Then
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Else
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
    End If

    If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
    If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

    Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

End Function

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31655083/4035833)? It looks like it will solve your issue. Are all the columns on one sheet or multiple? Also people are typically more likely to help you if you post examples of what you have written and what you are trying to achieve along with error messages if any that you are getting. You may also want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes I have tried the one you have referred. But when I run macro nothing changes.
All my data are in one sheet. they have A-M column. all are contain email address. I want to check each email address for duplicate. If duplicate then delete it keeping original value. I have more than 5000 email in separate column.

Comment: Edit your question by adding the code as you have altered it so that people can see what you are doing.

Comment: I have added my code & data. Hopefully people can help me now :(

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Just replace the sheet number with the one that you are using. I have Sheet1 as a holder.

```
 Sub RemoveDups()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim col As Range

For Each col In Sheet2.Range("A:C").Columns
    Sheet1.Range(col.Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Next col

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed sheet number according to your instruction and then i run it. Nothing happened.

Comment: Looking at your code it looks like you needed sheet2 and columns A:C. Everything is working on my end, but it looks like in the data you posted that there aren't any duplicates.

Comment: I dont know why it is not happening in my side.

If i paste this code then prompt appears "object required"

I have changed sheet2 in both case and column range A:C. Also i have added some duplicate value to make sure.

Comment: It should not say, "object required". All objects are defined within that sub routine. Maybe you should add it to a whole new module. I do not know if you have any other sub routines in that module or what.

Comment: still not working for me. Thank you for your help. I have solved it by excel ablebits add-inn. :)